# Swipe Views in Android

Tags: android

I have written an Android App, which uses ViewPager to swipe between different Views of my app. This works very well, but the animation isn't like I want it to be.
The current view swipes out to the right, and the new enters from left. But I want the current view to leave like a layer to the right, so that the user can see the new view, which was "under" the current view. I want the "old" view to stay at the right side, so it can return onclick.
The current Evernote App uses this behaviour. I attached a screenshot. Thanks ;-)!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RlT4.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [Sliding-Sidebar](https://github.com/walkingice/gui-sliding-sidebar). This has Facebook like slideout effect.

Quick reference of the above library :

You can download the [Android UI Patterns](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns&hl=en) app. from the Google Play and see the effects you require. Its inside `ActionBar & Dashboard --> gui-sliding-sidebar`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, thats the effect I needed. But this is no gesture swipe, it only swipes by button press. Is there a possibility to wipe with the gesture?

Comment: you can detect swipe in your activity and open the sidebar instead of button. Try it.

Comment: Yes, this works. You can use the toggleSidebar(); Method to (un)hide the sidebar. You can start the (un)hide process with a gesture, too. But it seems not possible, to swipe. I want the overlay to move like the finger, and not like a defined animation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the fly in app menu here below demo project will help you

https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) It is a very good and solid library with an active developer. It works well with ActionbarSherlock too which is great for backwards compatibility.

> SlidingMenu
>   An Android library that allows developers to easily create slide-in menus like in the Spotify and Facebook applications.